# azure-devops-node-api: Authenticate with username and password

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am new to node.js 'azure-devops-node-api'. I want to connect with my collection, getPersonalAccessTokenHandler(token) method works fine, But I want to authenticate with username and password. getNtlmHandler(username, password) do authenticates but I am unable to get respositories with this approach. Kindly suggest me a better method to authenticate please

```
const azdev = require("azure-devops-node-api");

const collectionURL = 'https://dev.azure.com/username';
let authHandler = azdev.getNtlmHandler('username', 'password');
let connection = new azdev.WebApi(collectionURL, authHandler);

connection.connect().then(connData => {
    console.log(`Connection established successfully!!!. This is 
    ${connData.authenticatedUser.providerDisplayName}. Welcome!!!`);

    connection.getGitApi().then(vstsGit => {
        vstsGit.getRepositories('projectName').then(repos => {

            // repos is null or undefined
            console.log('There are', repos.length, 'repositories in this 
            project');
            // But When I authenticates with Token, It works fine.

        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When looking to the `azure-devops-node-api` source code, you can see that there are 4 different ways to authenticate.

```
export function getBasicHandler(username: string, password: string): VsoBaseInterfaces.IRequestHandler {
    return new basicm.BasicCredentialHandler(username, password);
}

export function getNtlmHandler(username: string, password: string, workstation?: string, domain?: string): VsoBaseInterfaces.IRequestHandler {
    return new ntlmm.NtlmCredentialHandler(username, password, workstation, domain);
}

export function getBearerHandler(token: string): VsoBaseInterfaces.IRequestHandler {
    return new bearm.BearerCredentialHandler(token);
}

export function getPersonalAccessTokenHandler(token: string): VsoBaseInterfaces.IRequestHandler {
    return new patm.PersonalAccessTokenCredentialHandler(token);
}
```

Because you are only passing the Username and Password you can also use `getBasicHandler()` to authenticate.

---

Beside this, be sure that your security settings are configured in the right way.
For example `Alternate authentication credentials` has to be **toggled on** in the security policies of your organisation to make use of basic authentication for the REST Api.

Azure DevOps Security reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-application-access-policies?view=azure-devops